# QuickSort code doesn't work properly

Tags: c++, quicksort

```
int main()
    {
        int numbers[size] = {14, 7, 23, 31, 1, 20, 6, 3, 40, 5}, start, finish;

        cout << "Numbers are: " << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            cout << numbers[i] << "\t";
        }

        finish = 10;
        start = 0;

        quickSort(numbers, start, finish);

        cout << "\n\nSorted: " << endl;
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            cout << numbers[j] << "\t";
        }

        return 0;
    }

int Partition(int numbers[], int start, int finish)
{

    int pole = start;
    int pivot = numbers[finish];

    for (int k = 0; k < finish - 1; k++)
    {
        if (numbers[k] <= pivot)
        {
            int temp = numbers[k];
            numbers[k] = numbers[pole];
            numbers[pole] = temp;

            pole++;
        }
    }

    int temp2 = numbers[pole];
    numbers[pole] = numbers[pivot];
    numbers[pivot] = temp2;

    return pole;
}

void quickSort(int numbers[], int start, int finish)
{
    int marker;
    if (start < finish)
    {
        marker = Partition(numbers, start, finish);
        quickSort(numbers, start, marker - 1);
        quickSort(numbers, marker + 1, finish);
    }
}
```

I feel like I'm missing something but I couldn't figure out what. The program doesn't sort properly. Need some help! I tried to cout in the middle of the process to spot where the problem is, from what I understand, it doesn't sort it completely. Well, I'm not sure myself. I'm still new to recursive so I might have done something wrong.

Comment: `int pivot = numbers[finish];` reads beyond the end of the array. It's time for you to do some debugging.

Comment: ahh, I set my finish = 10, fixed to 9. But it still doesn't sort properly.

Comment: No, that's wrong. I reverted your edit. Please don't make this a moving target.

Comment: I tried for(int k = start; k < finish - 1; k++) like you suggested, the value 40 somehow turned to 0 in my output.

Comment: Fixed my error with the one you suggested, came out really close, my value 7 somehow ended up in the middle of the array.

Comment: Make all the changes in my answer and you will be there

Comment: Ahhhh got it working now. Thanks for your help, mate. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
finish = 10;
```

you should write

```
finish = size;
```

In the partition function you wrote

```
int pivot = numbers[finish];
```

This reads beyond the end of the array. You meant

```
int pivot = numbers[finish - 1];
```

In your partition function you run a loop like this:

```
for (int k = 0; k < finish - 1; k++)
```

That starts from the beginning of the entire array. It should be:

```
for (int k = start; k < finish - 1; k++)
```

The final step of your partition function is wrong:

```
int temp2 = numbers[pole];
numbers[pole] = numbers[pivot];
numbers[pivot] = temp2;
```

That uses the pivot value rather than the pivot index. It should be:

```
int temp2 = numbers[pole];
numbers[pole] = numbers[finish - 1];
numbers[finish - 1] = temp2;
```

The implementation of `quickSort` is also wrong:

```
marker = Partition(numbers, start, finish);
quickSort(numbers, start, marker - 1);
quickSort(numbers, marker + 1, finish);
```

should be:

```
marker = Partition(numbers, start, finish);
quickSort(numbers, start, marker);
quickSort(numbers, marker + 1, finish);
```

---

The above changes fix your code.

More fundamentally I think you need to be clearer about what `start` and `finish` mean. They follow the convention that `start` is the index of the first item, and `finish` is one greater than the index of the last item. Many of the errors above were down to off-by-one errors due to not fully comprehending this convention.

Comment: +1 :-) Why don't you just write a new quicksort as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main(){
int numbers[] = {14, 7, 23, 31, 1, 20, 6, 3, 40, 5};
const int size = sizeof(numbers)/sizeof(int);

cout << "Numbers are: " << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    cout << numbers[i] << "\t";
}

quickSort(numbers, 0, size - 1);//This is the first place you should take care of!
                                //What do you want the third parameter represent?
                                //1.the greatest index of the array;or 2. the length of the array
                                //Here goes the first choose, so size-1
cout << "Sorted: " << endl;
for (int j = 0; j < size; j++){
    cout << numbers[j] << "\t";
} 
return 0;
}

int Partition(int num[], int start, int finish){
int temp;
int pole = start;
int pivot = num[finish];

for (int k = start; k <= finish - 1; k++){//as I mentioned above, choose 1 , so there must be =
    if (num[k] <= pivot){
        temp = num[k];
        num[k] = num[pole];
        num[pole] = temp;

        pole++;
    }
}

temp = num[pole];
num[pole] = num[finish];//you did something wrong here!!
num[finish] = temp;//And here.Not pivot.

return pole;
}

void quickSort(int num[], int start, int finish){
int marker;
if (start < finish){
    marker = Partition(num, start, finish);
    quickSort(num, start, marker - 1);//And here, num[marker] is in its final place,so ending with marker-1 will be fine. 
                                      //Of course, you also can replace it with marker.
    quickSort(num, marker + 1, finish); 
}
}
```